# the app not working with the phone emulator

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk

My app work normal when i use the chrome emulator but when i use a real phone or phone emulator not working and i get this error

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction Android resource linking failed**

```
    package="com.example.birthday">
   <application
        android:label="birthday"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|gender|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\firstDart\flutter project\birthday\birthday\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:23: AAPT: error: 'orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|gender|uiMode' is incompatible with attribute configChanges (attr) flags [colorMode=16384, density=4096, fontScale=1073741824, fontWeightAdjustment=268435456, keyboard=16, keyboardHidden=32, layoutDirection=8192, locale=4, mcc=1, mnc=2, navigation=64, orientation=128, screenLayout=256, screenSize=1024, smallestScreenSize=2048, touchscreen=8, uiMode=512].

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 20s

Comment: can you provide the whole error code ?

Comment: @FahmiSawalha i add it to the question

Comment: What is gender in `android:configChanges` ?, I didn't find the value [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config)

Comment: @ShashankGb it is a variable string in my code

Comment: which version of sdk you are using? and where is that variable declared ?